# Holographic principle and Huygens principle

Tags: waves, holographic-principle, huygens-principle

I have recently read about the information paradox of black holes and how it lead eventually to the formulation of the holographic principle. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle):

> "the description of a volume of space can be thought of as encoded on a lower-dimensional boundary to the region — preferably a light-like boundary like a gravitational horizon."

There is a branch of classical physics, where a very similar sounding principle is nowadays almost trivially well-known, namely the field of linear wave propagation (in the language of mathematics, linear hyperbolic PDEs of second order). Huygens' principle, as it was later encoded in [Kirchhoff's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff_integral_theorem), states roughly that in order to "understand" (i.e. predict, calculate) the wave propagation in a volume, you just need boundary values on the surface of the volume.

Is there any deeper mathematical connection between the holographic and  Huygens' principle, or is this pure coincidence?